# How to create separate DropdownIndicator component using React-select so that it can be reused in other part of the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

The below code works fine when I keep the DropdownIndicator component in the same file.

But I want to keep DropdownIndicator in separate file so that it can be reused. Like keep it separate component and use it in other files like wherever required in dropdown fields to show the caret up and down icon.

similar example like below

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCaretDown, faCaretUp } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import "./styles.css";

library.add(faCaretDown);
library.add(faCaretUp);

const colourOptions = [
  {
    label: "Orange",
    value: "orange"
  },
  {
    label: "Blue",
    value: "blue"
  },
  {
    label: "Purple",
    value: "purple"
  }
];

const Placeholder = (props) => {
  return <components.Placeholder {...props} />;
};
let isOpen = false;
const CaretDownIcon = () => {
  return <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-down" />;
};

const CaretUpIcon = () => {
  return <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-up" />;
};

const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {
  return (
    <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
      {isOpen ? <CaretDownIcon /> : <CaretUpIcon />}
    </components.DropdownIndicator>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        onMenuOpen={() => (isOpen = true)}
        onMenuClose={() => (isOpen = false)}
        components={{ Placeholder, DropdownIndicator }}
        placeholder={"Choose"}
        styles={{
          placeholder: (base) => ({
            ...base,
            fontSize: "1em",
            color: colourOptions[2].value,
            fontWeight: 400
          })
        }}
        options={colourOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? It would be ideal if you could prepare some working example in code sandbox or similar.

Comment: Thanks for making the code a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the way you're holding the isOpen flag is not ideal as it would make the indicators change for all present Selects.

To extract the component you could leverage the [select props](https://react-select.com/props#select-props) passed to the custom DropdownIndicator and use that instead of your flag.

Here's a working sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-dropdown-indicator-5shel

Comment: This works absolutely perfect, and now I am able to use the CustomDropdownIndicator in other places. thanks.